# How does Linux load the 'initrd' image?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, initrd

I've been trying to understand the booting process, but there's just one thing that is going over my head..

> As soon as the Linux kernel has been booted and the root file system (/) mounted, programs can be run and further kernel modules can be integrated to provide additional functions. To mount the root file system, certain conditions must be met. The kernel needs the corresponding drivers to access the device on which the root file system is located (especially SCSI drivers). The kernel must also contain the code needed to read the file system (ext2, reiserfs, romfs, etc.). It is also conceivable that the root file system is already encrypted. In this case, a password is needed to mount the file system.
>
> The initial ramdisk (also called initdisk or initrd) solves precisely the problems described above. The Linux kernel provides an option of having a small file system loaded to a RAM disk and running programs there before the actual root file system is mounted. **The loading of initrd is handled by the boot loader (GRUB, LILO, etc.). Boot loaders only need BIOS routines to load data from the boot medium.** If the boot loader is able to load the kernel, it can also load the initial ramdisk. Special drivers are not required.

If /boot is not a different partition, but is present in the / partition, then shouldn't the boot loader require the SCSI drivers, to access the 'initrd' image and the kernel image? If you can access the images directly, then why exactly do we need the SCSI drivers??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nighpher, I'll try to answer your question, but for a more comprehensive description of boot process, try [this article at IBM](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/l-linuxboot/).

Ok, I assume, that you are using GRUB or GRUB2 as your bootloader for explanation. First off, when BIOS accesses your disk to load the bootloader, it makes use of its built-in routines for disk access, which are stored in the famous 13h interrupt. Bootloader (and kernel at setup phase) make use of those routines when they access disk. Note that BIOS runs in real mode (16-bit mode) of the processor, thus it cannot address more than 2^20 bytes of RAM (2^20, not 2^16, because each address in real mode is comprised of segment_address*16 + offset, where both segment address and offset are 16-bit, see ["x86 memory segmentation" at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation)). Thus, these routines can't access more than 1 MiB of RAM, which is a strict limitation and a major inconvenience.

BIOS loads bootloader code right from the MBR – the first 512 bytes of your disk – and executes it. If you're using GRUB, that code is GRUB stage 1. That code loads GRUB stage 1.5, which is located either in the first 32 KiB of disk space, called DOS compatibility region, or from a fixed address of the file system. It doesn't need to understand the file system structure to do this, because even if stage 1.5 is in the file system, it is "raw" code and can be directly loaded to RAM and executed: See ["Details of GRUB on the PC" at pixelbeat.org](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/disk/), which is the source for the below image. Load of stage 1.5 from disk to RAM makes use of BIOS disk access routines.

[image]

Stage 1.5 contains the filesystem utilities, so that it can read the stage 2 from the filesystem (well, it still uses BIOS 13h to read from disk to RAM, but now it can decipher filesystem info about inodes, etc., and get raw code out of the disk). Older BIOSes might not be able to access the whole HD due to limitations in their disk addressing mode – they might use Cylinder-Head-Sector system, unable to address more than first 8 GiB of disk space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector.

Stage 2 **loads the kernel** into RAM (again, using BIOS disk utilities). If it's 2.6+ kernel, it also has initramfs compiled within, so no need to load it. If it's an older kernel, bootloader also loads standalone initrd image into memory, so that kernel could mount it and get drivers for mounting real file system from disk.

The problem is that the kernel (and ramdisk) weigh more than 1 MiB; thus, to load them into RAM you have to load the kernel into the first 1 MiB, then jump to protected mode (32-bit), move the loaded kernel to high memory (free the first 1 MiB for real mode), then return to real (16-bit) mode again, get ramdisk from disk to first 1 MiB (if it's a separate initrd and older kernel), possibly switch to protected (32-bit) mode again, put it to where it belongs, possibly get back to real mode (or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821911/does-grub-switch-to-protected-mode) and execute the kernel code. Warning: I'm not entirely sure about thoroughness and accuracy of this part of description.

Now, **when you finally run the kernel, you already have it and ramdisk loaded into RAM by bootloader**, so the kernel can use disk utilities from ramdisk to mount your real root file system and pivot root to it. ramfs drivers are present in the kernel, so it can understand the contents of initramfs, of course.

Comment: Can't the bootlader just load the kernel in chunks, instead of jumping into protected mode?? And what is the need for freeing that 1 MB..(Sorry.. couldn't understand that..)

Comment: The need for freeing first 1MiB is as follows: bootloader can access your hard drive only in real mode, cause it accesses it with BIOS utilities, which are real-mode (they operate on 16-bit arguments and use 16-bit operations). Real mode just doesn't see any RAM except by first 1 MiB. But you need to load kernel+initramfs into RAM and they take ~5 MiB space in RAM. Those BIOS utilities just won't be able to squeeze 5 MiB into the first 1 MiB. So, bootloader has to copy them from disk to first 1 MiB, then go to protected mode and move them from first 1Mb RAM to higher RAM. Is it clearer now? :)

Comment: Ahh.. that explains it!! Also thanks for the [pixelbeat link](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/disk/).. (The pictures helped out a lot!!)

Comment: Great! Oh, why aren't we explaining everything with pictures and cartoons, words are so inconvenient...

Comment: The whole stage 1/1.5/2 stuff is grub legacy.

Comment: @psusi Yep, but not entirely. See correspondence of legacy grub and grub2 modules in http://pixelbeat.org/docs/disk or in official documentation.

Comment: great explanation! So this is why I have to call the first disk's first partition hd0,0 in grub, /dev/sda1 in Linux and why both don't necessarily match.

Comment: Is stage 2 inside `/boot` as demonstrated by your diagram? Is the kernel able to access `/boot` as well during stage 2? For example if I put a file inside `/boot` can GRUB or the kernel or the `init.sh` loaded at stage 2 read a file from `/boot`? Or is contained inside the initramfs?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes, stage2 bootloader is in the filesystem (namely, in `/boot` partition). Kernel is not loaded at this point - it's grub's stage1.5, who's accessing stage2 in the `/boot` filesystem (e.g. in `/boot/grub` file) via its minimalistic filesystem drivers. Kernel will also be able to read from `/boot` partition, but it will happen later, after execution of grub2 code and load of kernel and after kernel reads initramfs. Are you speaking of `init.sh` of the initramfs? It resides in `/boot` partition of your hard drive, then stage2 of grub puts it into RAM and  Kernel reads it from RAM.

Comment: Are you sure the bootloader loads the initrd into RAM? If that's the case, why is the path to the initrd file given to the kernel as a boot parameter?

Comment: @joonas.fi Thank you so much for this question and making me do a research on the matter, cause I was stuck with obsolete vision of the things! Indeed, in 2.4- kernels initrd was a separate file, loaded into RAM by the bootloader: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/initrd.html. In modern-ish kernels (2.6+, technically, even 2.5.something+), initramfs is linked into kernel at compile time - hence the kernel parameter: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt. Cheers!

Comment: @Boris Burkov, about your last comment: I see initrd file in modern (2018) distros, like Linux Mint. How is it so?

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov It's a weird twist of life, Alexei. 1.5 years after my comment I can't recall anything on the subject, as I haven't been working with Linux since those times and my head is currently overburdened with totally different stuff. Sorry that I can't help you.

Comment: Initrd *had to* be a separate file. The newer initramfs *can be* linked to the kernel, but it does not *have to be* - it can also be loaded as a separate file by the bootloader. Since the initramfs file is defined as a sequence of cpio archives, some bootloaders (e.g. iPXE) even allow *multiple* initramfs files, which will be loaded into memory one after another. Also, some Linux distributions use initrd-style file names for backwards compatibility, although the actual technology used is now initramfs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, it boils down to what features particular bootloader supports.
Eg. it doesn't have to know particular filesystem of your combined (boot + root) partition. In that case you just create a separate boot partition in condition such that it works with your bootloader, and any other complexity of how to mount your root partition is left on the kernel and initrd image booted from boot partition. Bootloader does know how to access the SCSI devices (and other devices too, depending on what bootloader is used) either by using it's own drivers or by utilizing BIOS routines. Moreover, it knows how to read some filesystems, etc.

Consider eg. UEFI way of booting, where actually UEFI firmware already know how to access EFI partition, read it and load linux kernel from there without need of intermediate bootloader. In that case the linux image lives separated from root partition and UEFI firmware doesn't have to know all exotic filesystems to access it. I believe separation of "boot" images from "root" partition make big sense. If not for anything else then this is necessity when setting up root filesystem encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, if a bootloader does *not* load initrd it's worthwhile to test another bootloader; I've just ran into a situation like [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/initrd-not-being-run-on-boot-from-lilo-4175531281/) when LILO silently ignored a properly specified initrd of medium size (<4Mb; single ext4 rootfs on a SATA SSD; GPT) and GRUB 2.00 succeeded.

The boot process ended quickly with a typical

```
RAMDISK: Couldn't find valid RAM disk image starting at 0.
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,3)
```